# Report Generation API for use on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports

I have used *JasperReports* in past Java projects in combination with iReport for building dynamic reports that run against a database, but I understand that Google App Engine does not support *JasperReports*. Can anyone point me to something similar, or a report generation mechanism that is compatible with GAE?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you made any progress on this ( if you did please let us know!)

As far as I know The GAE team has marked [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1423) as NO-FIX. My suggestion is to try:
1) [PDF Jet](http://pdfjet.com/) + [Jcharts](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/) , both are pure java and do not depend on any of the balcklisted classes. I've has some limited succes with this.

2) Using [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/) which are not limited as the standard sandbox.

3) Finnaly, using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) to create your docs (using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server)) and then just provide the export URL for PDF.

To be honest I ended up doing #3, while being a little more complex in the long run i found some additional benefits of having my reports pre-built and hosted on Drive.

Hope it helps.